# How to access Sharepoint files using app-level authentication / access token?

Tags: c#, azure, api, sharepoint

I am trying to access Sharepoint files without having to have the user login.

I can get an access token by either
Method 1:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://login.microsoftonline.com/app's-tenant-id-here/oauth2/token");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "fpc=AjMRWuGtzbFJgrxV0V1kMCkUHKO3AQAAAEqqRtgOAAAA");
request.AddParameter("resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com");
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
request.AddParameter("client_id", "client-id-here");
request.AddParameter("client_secret", ".client-secret-here");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

or Method 2 -
(This one gives the following error: *The type initializer for 'AppForSharePointOnlineWebToolkit.TokenHelper' threw an exception*.)

```
string siteUrl = "https://the-site-I-am-trying-to-access.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/";
string realm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(new Uri(siteUrl));
string accessToken2 = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, new Uri(siteUrl).Authority, realm).AccessToken;
using (ClientContext cc = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(siteUrl, accessToken2))
{
       cc.Load(cc.Web, p => p.Title);
       cc.ExecuteQuery();
       Console.WriteLine(cc.Web.Title);
}
```

And even method 3

```
HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://the-site-I-am-trying-to-access.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('~/Shared%20Documents/picture.png')");
endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
```

None of which successfully access Sharepoint.

So my question is, am I doing something wrong or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all I would suggest to use Graph API if possible. At least it's the preferred way to query data and it makes things a lot easier.

To access data inside the Microsoft 365 world via Graph API it's required to create a new app registration inside the [azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/#home) > Azure Active Directory > App Registrations.

See this link for more information: [MS Docs App Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/auth-register-app-v2?view=graph-rest-1.0)

After you've created a new app, configure the required scope and permissions to access SharePoint data (e.g. `Sites.ReadWrite.All` for full access).

After that simply use the generated and provided clientID, clientSecret, tenantID and scope to request a new access token.

I created a Class to carry out all the http requests for me:

```cs
public class GraphClient
{
  private const string LOGIN_URL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
  private const string BASE_URL  = "https://graph.microsoft.com";

  protected internal string HttpBaseAddress { get; }

  protected internal readonly HttpClient HttpClient;

  public GraphClient(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret, string version = "1.0")
  {
    var msgHandler = new GraphAuthMessageHandler(string.Format(LOGIN_URL, tenantId),
                                                         $"{BASE_URL}/.default",
                                                         clientId,
                                                         clientSecret,
                                                         new HttpClientHandler());
    HttpBaseAddress = $"{BASE_URL}/v{version}/";
    HttpClient = new HttpClient(msgHandler)
    {
      BaseAddress = new Uri(HttpBaseAddress),
      Timeout     = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0)
    };

    HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
    HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
    HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
  }
}
```

The provided MessageHangler requests the token and adds the provided access token to the header:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class GraphAuthMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
  private readonly string _loginUrl;
  private readonly string _clientId;
  private readonly string _clientSecret;
  private readonly string _scope;

  public GraphAuthMessageHandler(string loginUrl, string scope, string clientId, string clientSecret, HttpMessageHandler innerHandler)
            : base(innerHandler)
  {
    _loginUrl     = loginUrl;
    _clientId     = clientId;
    _clientSecret = clientSecret;
    _scope        = scope;
  }

  protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    var result = await AcquireAccessToken();
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(result.TokenType, result.AccessToken);

    return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
  }

  private async Task<AuthResponse> AcquireAccessToken()
  {
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
      new("client_id", _clientId),
      new("client_secret", _clientSecret),
      new("scope", _scope),
      new("grant_type", "client_credentials")
    };

    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(_loginUrl, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
    return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<AuthResponse>();
  }
}
```

*Edit* Here's the AuthResponse class, that simply maps the json response to an C# Object:

```cs
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class AuthResponse
{
  [JsonPropertyName("token_type")]   public string TokenType   { get; set; }
  [JsonPropertyName("expires_in")]   public int    ExpiresIn   { get; set; }
  [JsonPropertyName("access_token")] public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

And then simply use it:

```cs
var driveId = "your-drive-id-here";
var itemId = "your-item-id-here";
var client = new GraphClient(TENANT_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);

var response = await client.HttpClient.GetAsync($"drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/content");

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  var fileStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
  // do something with stream
}

// handle errors here
```

The [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0) are a good start to get it working, it helped me a lot about using Graph API and also the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to test queries and requests to the endpoint.

P.S. this is just a simple example and for sure there's room for improvements, but this will hopefully point you to the right direction ;)

Comment: Very good answer thank you! I just have 2 stupid questions, what exactly is the AuthResponse being returned from the AcquireAccessToken() method? How do I get an item's ID?

Comment: I've edited the answer and added the missing AuthResponse class, it simply maps the json response to the needed properties.

You can get the itemID's from doing some requests inside the Graph Explorer. There are several template requests on the left pane under OneDrive, for example to list your own items it makes a GET request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children`. The json response contains the items and also the itemID's you're gonna need.

Pls. mark the answer as correct if it helped you, thanks :)

Comment: I'm only back on this project next week so I can't confirm if it worked but I will mark it, thank you very much