# How to get Documents from Share Point Online Team Site using Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft365

I am trying to get the files from a Folder located in SharePoint online Team Site.
I could get the Team Site using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=displayName eq 'DemoSite'&$select=id,displayName
```

How can I get the folders and files available in this Team site using graph API?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67776564/2238110)

Answer (score 0):

First get the groupId using
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=displayName eq '" + SiteName + "'&$select=id,displayName](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=displayName%20eq%20%27%22%20%20%20SiteName%20%20%20%22%27&$select=id,displayName)

and then use,

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/" + groupId + "/drive/items/root:/{$item_path}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%22%20+%20groupId%20+%20%22/drive/items/root:/%7B$item_path%7D)